# Эрик Мэтиз - Изучаем Python, Alien Invasion, Глава 12, ошибка "Unresolved attribute reference"

Tags: python, классы, pygame, спрайт

Занимаюсь по книге Эрика Мэтиза, код пишу такой же, как показан в примерах. При этом все равно возникают ошибки.

Код основной программы:

```
import sys
import pygame
from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship
from bullet import Bullet
from alien import Alien


class AlienInvasion:  # управление ресурсами и поведением игры
    def __init__(self):  # создание игровых ресурсов
        pygame.init()
        self.settings = Settings()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
        self.settings.screen_width = self.screen.get_rect().width
        self.settings.screen_height = self.screen.get_rect().height
        pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")
        self.ship = Ship(self.screen)
        self.bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.aliens = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self._create_fleet()

    def run_game(self):
        while True:
            self._check_events()
            self.ship.update()
            self._update_bullets()
            self._update_aliens()
            self._upgrade_screen()

    def _check_events(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():  # отслеживание клавиатуры и мыши
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                self._check_keydown_events(event)
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                self._check_keyup_events(event)

    def _check_keydown_events(self, event):
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            self.ship.moving_right = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            self.ship.moving_left = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            self._fire_bullet()

    def _check_keyup_events(self, event):
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            self.ship.moving_right = False
        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            self.ship.moving_left = False

    def _upgrade_screen(self):
        self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)  # экран перерисовывается
        self.ship.blitme()
        for bullet in self.bullets.sprites():
            bullet.draw_bullet()
        self.aliens.draw(self.screen)
        pygame.display.flip()  # отображение последнего прорисованного экрана

    def _fire_bullet(self):
        if len(self.bullets) < self.settings.bullets_allowed:
            new_bullet = Bullet(self.screen, self.ship)
            self.bullets.add(new_bullet)

    def _update_bullets(self):
        self.bullets.update()
        for bullet in self.bullets.copy():
            if bullet.rect.bottom <= 0:
                self.bullets.remove(bullet)

    def _update_aliens(self):
        self.aliens.update()

    def _create_fleet(self):
        alien = Alien(self)
        alien_width, alien_height = alien.rect.size
        ship_height = self.ship.rect.height
        available_space_x = self.settings.screen_width - (2 * alien_width)
        available_space_y = self.settings.screen_height - ship_height - (3 * alien_height)
        number_aliens_x = available_space_x // (2 * alien_width)
        number_rows = available_space_y // (2 * alien_height)
        for row_number in range(number_rows):
            for alien_number in range(number_aliens_x):
                self._create_alien(alien_number, row_number, alien_width, alien_height)

    def _create_alien(self, alien_number, row_number, alien_width, alien_height):
        alien = Alien(self)
        alien.x = alien_width + 2 * alien_width * alien_number
        alien.rect.x = alien.x
        alien.rect.y = alien.rect.height + 2 * alien_height * row_number
        self.aliens.add(alien)

    def _check_fleet_edges(self):
        for alien in self.aliens.sprites():
            if alien.check_edges():
                self.change_fleet_direction()
                break

    def change_fleet_direction(self):
        for alien in self.aliens.sprites():
            alien.rect.y += self.settings.fleet_drop_speed
        self.settings.fleet_direction *= -1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ai = AlienInvasion()
    ai.run_game()
```

Ошибки возникают в строчках:

if alien.check_edges(): - Unresolved attribute reference 'check_edges' for class 'Sprite'

bullet.draw_bullet() - Unresolved attribute reference 'draw_bullet' for class 'Sprite'

Насколько я понимаю, проблема в том, что у класса Sprite нет методов check_edges() и draw_bullet()

Но, я создавал классы Bullet и Alien в отдельных файлах:

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite
from settings import Settings


class Bullet(Sprite):
    def __init__(self, ai_game, ship):
        # создание снаряда в позиции корабля
        super().__init__()
        self.screen = ai_game
        self.settings = Settings()
        self.color = self.settings.bullet_color

        # Создание снаряда в (0, 0) и назначение правильной позиции
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, self.settings.bullet_width, self.settings.bullet_height)
        self.rect.midtop = ship.rect.midtop

        # Позиция снаряда в вещественном формате
        self.y = float(self.rect.y)

    def update(self):
        self.y -= self.settings.bullet_speed
        self.rect.y = self.y

    def draw_bullet(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.color, self.rect)
```

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite
from settings import Settings


class Alien(Sprite):

    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        super().__init__()
        self.screen = ai_game
        self.settings = Settings()
        self.image = pygame.image.load('data/alien.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        # каждый пришелец появляется в верхнем левом углу
        self.rect.x = self.rect.width
        self.rect.y = self.rect.height

        self.x = float(self.rect.x)

    def update(self):
        self.x += (self.settings.alien_speed * self.settings.fleet_direction)
        self.rect.x = self.x

    def check_edges(self):
        screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
        if self.rect.right >= screen_rect.right or self.rect.left <= 0:
            return True
```

Эти классы наследуются от класса Sprite

В основной программе bullet - экземпляр класса Sprite, почему тогда он не видит методов класса-последователя?

Так же я пробовал bullet.Bullet.draw_bullet(), но тоже не помогло - Unresolved attribute reference 'Bullet' for class 'Sprite'

Как решить данную проблему?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
def _check_fleet_edges(self):
    for alien in self.aliens.sprites():
                            ^^^^^^^^^^
        if alien.check_edges():
            self.change_fleet_direction()
            break
```

Так зачем вы берёте у `aliens` спрайты `sprites()`, если вам нужны объекты `Alien` и их методы, а не объекты `Sprite`? Перебирайте просто `aliens` и всё:

```
def _check_fleet_edges(self):
    for alien in self.aliens:
        if alien.check_edges():
            self.change_fleet_direction()
            break
```

И с `Bullet` точно такая же петрушка с ненужными вам спрайтами:

```
    for bullet in self.bullets.sprites():
                              ^^^^^^^^^^
        bullet.draw_bullet()
```

Перебирайте объекты `Bullet`, в которых и лежат нужные вам свойства:

```
    for bullet in self.bullets:
        bullet.draw_bullet()
```

И для общего развития: наследование в обратную сторону не работает. У `Bullet` и `Alien` есть методы и поля из класса-предка `Sprite`, но не наоборот. У `Sprite` нет методов и полей, описанных в его наследниках `Bullet` и `Alien`.

Comment: Я и этот вариант пробовал, но он выдает ту же самую ошибку

Comment: Что-то я не верю. Попробуйте этот вариант и перед вызовом проблемных функций поставьте `print(type(alien))` и `print(type(bullet))`, может у вас там вообще в перемешку разные типы объектов в эти списки добавляются?

Comment: для bullet вывел <class 'bullet.Bullet'>
для alien не дошел до вывода, вставлял в таком виде:
`
        for alien in self.aliens.sprites():
            print(type(alien))

            if alien.check_edges():
`
Изменил вопрос, добавив в конце скриншот, что ошибка осталась

Answer (score -1):

если знаешь инглиш, вот ссылка, там у человека такая же проблема и ее решили успешно

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67030378/python-crash-course-alien-invasion-chapter-12-unresolved-attribute-referenc?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Там автор допустил ошибку/опечатку, которой у меня нет, но проблема осталась